# Which process calls do_dentry_open()?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When any special device file opening, do_dentry_open() function has been called. How to find out which process has called do_dentry_open() function?

Comment: The function is called by the process, which wants to work with file. E.g., if it is `open()` file.

Comment: I understand. The question is how to get process name from do_dentry_open(). I have possibility modify kernel sources and compile kernel in accornance with my needs. What structures and fields can be used to restore process name?

Comment: `current` is a pointer to object of type`struct task_struct`, which describe currently executed task(process).`.comm` field of this object contains process name.